# How do you implement the ? help, where user clicks ? and then clicks a control for more help?

Tags: vb.net

I don't even know what this is called. But some Windows apps used to have a "?" near the X in upper right corner. You could click that and then click on something on the screen and get help.

Anyone know what that's called or (better) have any pointers to instructions on how to implement it?

Oh, and I'm using vb.net 2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called "What's This?" help.

Here is a Microsoft article on implementing it in Visual Basic. If you want another language, I hope this is enough of a pointer to get you there.

[How To Implement "What's This?" Help in Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142249)

Answer (score 2):

In .NET you can turn it on by setting the boolean field "HelpButton" on a form control. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.helpbutton.aspx) for more info. Additionally, there's an event that fires on clicking this button. Link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.helpbuttonclicked.aspx).

Hope that helps... Are you using .NET or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It's called [Context-sensitive help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_help); that's about all I know.

Comment: Context-sensitive Help is a more broad term than what Clay is looking for.

Comment: Well, it sort of is context sensitive though.

Comment: Not really.. Context sensitive help is where you press f1, and the program figures out what you want help with based on where in the program you are and what has focus. With "What's this" help, you explicitly click on the element you want help with.

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe is right:  this is a form of Context Sensitive help in the general sense (e.g. the way Wikipedia uses it.)  Microsoft have a more limited term (one I don't like much!) called What's This Help for this special case. They use Context Sensitive Help to mean what Blorgbeard describes.